# Exponential Object in a poset

Tags: category-theory

I have been trying to get to grips with what an exponential object is using a poset as an example.
So in the poset...
{2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 30, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84} x is related to y iff x is a factor of y.

I understand eg: hom(- x 60) is isomorphic to hom(-, 84^60)
so...

2x60 = 2... and 2->84

4*60 = 4... and 4->84

etc...

so the set of things that when producted with 60 the result is related to 84 is {2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 14, 36, 48, 72 84}.

So 84^60 is an object that all these objects is related to... but what exactly is 84^60 in this poset?

Is there a user friendly soundbite such as the product of two objects being the greatest common divisor?

...or have I got completely the wrong end of the stick?

Thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Why do you consider this on-topic for CS.SE?  It looks like a pure math question.  Our policy is that we expect you to describe in the question the connection to CS and why this question is best answered by CS experts (rather than math experts).  See the [help].  If you think this is more suitable for Math.SE, you can flag it for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it to Math.SE.